# How to set the default layout for the custom module?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

I am working on my first module and I stuck with frontend layout.

I created a block which I want to display in the right column.

In my `layout.xml` when I put my code in the `default` tag it is showing in my whole website, so i tried using this code `blog_default` tag but it is not showing anything.
How can I display my block in the right column.

Here is my `layout.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
 <reference name="root">   
  <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>   
</reference>
</default>
<blog_default>
  <reference name="right">
   <block type="blog/category_list" before="-" name="blog.category.list">
    <action method="setShowPopulatedOnly" ><show>1</show></action>
   </block>
   <block type="blog/widget_post_list" after="blog.category.list" name="blog.latest.posts"/>
 </reference>
</blog_default>
<blog_index_index>   
 <reference name="content">   
  <block type="blog/article_index" name="blog_index" template="blog/article/index.phtml"/>   
</reference>   
</blog_index_index>   
</layout>
```

by this the right column is not showing my block. How can I display my block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<default>` is used for all pages of the site.

As I understood you want to display your block on every page of your blog controller.

But magento does not support that. You need to place your block definition in every module controller_action_handle.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">   
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template>     </action>   
        </reference>
    </default>
    <blog_index_index>   
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="blog/category_list" before="-" name="blog.category.list">
                <action method="setShowPopulatedOnly" ><show>1</show></action>
            </block>
            <block type="blog/widget_post_list" after="blog.category.list" name="blog.latest.posts"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">   
            <block type="blog/article_index" name="blog_index" template="blog/article/index.phtml"/>   
        </reference>   
    </blog_index_index>
    <layout_handle>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="blog/category_list" before="-" name="blog.category.list">
                <action method="setShowPopulatedOnly" ><show>1</show></action>
            </block>
            <block type="blog/widget_post_list" after="blog.category.list" name="blog.latest.posts"/>
        </reference>
    </layout_handle> 
 </layout>
```

Where `layout_handle` is layout handle of every page you want to see a block.

Comment: I used this code already, but by this code it only showing in the blog page and when i moved to another page the block is gone from the right column.

Comment: You need to define it on those pages where you want to see it.

Comment: You want this block to be on every page?

Comment: yes I want this on every page in the blog module

Comment: Than you need to define it for every page you want to see it on.

Comment: but i see in some extension which i use before, there is a tag like this `<blog_default>` under the `<default>` tag for the layout option. I didn't understand it completely, If magento didn't support than how it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13055/discussion-between-waseem-and-oleksii-svarychevskyi)

Comment: I am happy to help.